# Firebase push notifications not working After uploading to the app store ios

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, app-store

after uploading the app to the app store notification not working any more
I've used both the key and certificate for development an production but both not working before uploading the app I've choose manually  provisioning profile and insure that it includes app notification capabilities 
but in the app store in ios build the Required Capabilities the is nothing

[image]

is that make any sense please help my I'm getting crazy I've try everything but nothing help

Answer (score 0):

Are you configured using [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs) guideline ?

Comment: Yes sure and more than this I'v try every thing but maybe there is something I've missed